# Trouble setting up static ip. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, static-ip

When I put in my subnet mask 255.255.255.248/29 it now says my ip is not contained in 255.255.255.248/29. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

`255.255.255.248` is already a subnet mask, not a subnet. The prefix `/29` is the representation of this subnet mask, so you don't add it.

Therefore your ip address is not contained in it.

The notation should be, for example in a private network:

```
192.168.1.1/24
```

where `/24` is equivalent to `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: I'm using a paid network. They gave me the subnet mask. ubuntu 18.04 will not let me continue with the install because of this problem. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What is the ip of the subnet?

Comment: Should I put my ip on here?

Answer (score 0):

I got subnet mask confused with subnet. I got the information from my provider.